# Oracle SQL PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting this error which seems to be an issue with column spelling.  However I am 99% percent sure I have spelled everything correct, but I can't see any reason to be getting the error I do...

Here's the source:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_qoh_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON sales
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_qoh products.qoh%TYPE;
    v_new_qoh products.qoh%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT qoh INTO v_qoh
    FROM products
    WHERE id = :new.product_id;

    v_new_qoh := v_qoh - new.quantity; // ERROR HERE

    UPDATE products
    SET qoh = :v_new_qoh
    WHERE id = :new.product_id;
END;
/
sho err
```

And that gives a:

```
12/12 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_NEW_QOH'
```

I have tried replacing line 12 with the following combinations:

- `v_new_qoh := :v_qoh - :new.quantity;`
- `:v_new_qoh := :v_qoh - :new.quantity;`
- `:v_new_qoh = :v_qoh - :new.quantity;`
- `:v_new_qoh := v_qoh - :new.quantity;`
- `:v_new_qoh := :v_qoh - new.quantity;`
- `v_new_qoh := v_qoh - :new.quantity;`

But it still gives me the error.

The products table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id NUMBER,
    name VARCHAR2,
    price NUMBER,
    qoh NUMBER(2)
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
    id NUMBER(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id NUBMER(3),
    product_id NUMBER(3),
    quantity NUMBER(2),
    price NUMBER(5,2),
    sale_date DATE,
    despatch_id NUMBER(10)
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add the definition of the `sales` table

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the update to:

```
UPDATE products
SET qoh = v_new_qoh
WHERE id = :new.product_id;
```

i.e. no colon in front of v_new_qoh.

The line number (12) refers to the line number of the PL/SQL block.
The block begins with the word DECLARE, so the 12th line is the one starting with:

```
SET qoh = :v_new_qoh
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  But I don't understand why it calls DECLARE line 12?  Is that in some code we can't see (cos I would say it is line 4)?

Comment: The DECLARE is line 1. That makes line 12: "SET qoh = :v_new_qoh".

Comment: No, I mean that the line with the error is line 12 if you count starting with DECLARE as line 1.

Answer (score 8):

and `new.quantity` should be `:new.quantity`

Answer (score 0):

for inserting same value of sample_insp_id in to Sir_no:-

```
update TRIGGER "PT"."BI_PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP"   
  before insert on "PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."SAMPLE_INSP_ID" is null then
    select "PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."SAMPLE_INSP_ID",:NEW."SIR_NO"from dual;
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create or replace trigger

```
"BI_PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP"
```

before insert on

```
"PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP"
```

for each row

```
begin   
    if :NEW."SAMPLE_INSP_ID" is null then
        select "PROJECT_PART_SAMPLE_INSP_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."SAMPLE_INSP_ID" from dual;
        :NEW."SIR_NO":= :NEW."SAMPLE_INSP_ID";
    end if;
end;
```