# Need to know the resolution for bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transaction_type_af_insert
AFTER INSERT ON transaction_type
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
aatype VARCHAR2(30);
action VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
CASE 
 WHEN INSERTING THEN
 action  :=  'After_Insert_transaction_type';
END CASE;
INSERT INTO transaction_type_log_history (aatype,  action) VALUES  
(:new.aatype,  action);
END;
/
SHOW ERROR;
```

I get below error:

> ```
> LINE/COL|ERROR
> 9/69    |PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.AATYPE'
> ```

The transaction_type table already has one 'type' column, so the code has been modified to take that value into the log table for the trigger. Corrected code which compiles without errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transaction_type_af_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON transaction_type
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
action VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
CASE 
WHEN INSERTING THEN
action := 'After_Insert_transaction_type';
END CASE;
INSERT INTO transaction_type_log_history (type, action)
VALUES (:new.type, action);
END;
/
SHOW ERROR;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL PLS-00049: bad bind variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244714/oracle-sql-pls-00049-bad-bind-variable)

Comment: I reused another code - CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_credit_bf_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON credit_card
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
cc_type VARCHAR(30);
action VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN
CASE 
WHEN UPDATING THEN
action := 'Before_Update_Credit_Card';
END CASE;
INSERT INTO credit_card_log_history (cc_type, action)
VALUES (:old.cc_type, action);
END
/

Comment: @Brien: I reused another trigger code with very similar contruct, the bind variable works there but not here/

Comment: there is a backtick character in this declaration: action`VARCHAR2(30); between variable name and datatype - you must remove it. Besides that, the trigger compiles fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the `create table` statement for the table `transaction_type`. [**EDIT**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49546813/edit) your question. Do **not** post code in comments

Comment: `WHEN INSERTING THEN` is useless as the trigger is defined as `after insert` - that condition will never be false

Comment: The issue is only with the variable aatype. I also removed the CASE and added the action value to the insert into case directly. I need not create the table transaction_type as it is already available, the assignment is only to create trigger:

Comment: The transaction_type table is: (P) id INTEGER, type VARCHAR2(255).

Comment: The assignment question is: Create a trigger named 'transaction_type_af_insert' that is triggered whenever a new record is inserted into transaction_type table. This trigger will insert the new type and action into the table 'transaction_type_log_history' after the insertion of transaction type details. The action name in the affected log table transaction_type_log_history is 'After_Insert_transaction_type'. Hints:
Trigger name : transaction_type_af_insert 
Table name : transaction_type_log_history 
Field names : type,action 
Action : 'After_Insert_transaction_type'.

Comment: Guys, thank you all for your help - I think i figured it out. The correct code is has been added to the description above. I think - since transaction_type table already has type as one of the columns, it should only insert a new value from that table into the log table. i removed the new variable aa_type.

Comment: @user1627288 It is great that you were able to work out a solution. Please feel free to post final solution as an answer (rather than including it in the question) and mark it as accepted (green tick).